# Martial arts vocabulary confusion

Tags: vocabulary

I'm trying to convert the romanized vocabulary in "The Art of Kyuki-Do" to 한글, and I can make sense of most of it. However, there are a couple of words that I haven't been able to find in my dictionary, or online:

- "Tahn-jeon", which the book defines as "slow pushing". I would expect it to be 단전 in 한글, but I'm not having any luck finding that word with a definition that makes sense in this context.
- "Bahn-sohn", which the book defines as "meditation". 반손 seems the logical spelling, but again, I can't find that as a word meaning "meditation".

Are these misspelled in the book? Or are they just obscure words? Thanks!

Comment: Tahn-jeon might be 단전, but bahn-sohn is.. well.. strange. Can you provide the context?

Comment: Sadly, there isn't much more context. There is a section of the book that lists Korean vocabulary, with the English word on the left, and the (romanized) Korean word on the right.

There is a section of the book that talks (briefly) about meditation as a tool for developing self-control, but it's all in English and aside from the vocabulary list, the book makes no references anywhere to "bahn-sohn".

Comment: Could Bahn-sohn be 반성?  This means self-reflection.

Comment: Ah, that sounds plausible! I've seen a few places where they've romanized things weird. I think I'm going to contact the author/publisher and see if they can clarify, but 반성 sounds likely.

Comment: 단전 means hypogastric, not slow pushing. Maybe you skipped another words? ex) slow pushing your breath to hypogastric?

Comment: Sadly, there's not a lot to go on. Searching the book (thank goodness for ebooks, right?), it looks like the phrase "slow pushing" appears only twice, not counting the vocab list. Both times use this exact phrasing: "Execute a _slow pushing_ twin high section horizontal block." Does that help at all?

Answer (score 1):

"Bahn-sohn" maybe is "Bang-song"(방송), 
and, go and see here ->
[https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/放鬆](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%94%BE%E9%AC%86)

Comment: Maybe you could explain here what it would mean in a Martial arts context?

Comment: Maybe this link would be helpful -> http://blog.daum.net/stone812/649     방송(放鬆) is much specialised word occasionally used in 기공학 (氣功學) - "방송(放鬆)" cannot be looked up at ordinary Korean dictionary - even not at Naver dictionary. 방송(放鬆) means "relax", and "relax" is important concept in meditation. And martial arts have immediate connection with Ki-gong(기공) and so on^^

Answer (score 0):

단전(Tahn-jeon) means speciffic point of the body.

[location of 단전](http://postfiles3.naver.net/MjAxNjExMjVfNjUg/MDAxNDgwMDUyOTg3MTA4.rNNtsAEF7h_NB6q0TY0DoEHPksYtr9AYcQT-dYxMnlkg.jsBBjtrp6JrOmyqD8eRCIc-QjXSLCQSBtNIwubaEsCkg.JPEG.b12144/%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A8%EC%A0%84.jpg?type=w2)